# how to set default language django-modeltranslation

Tags: django, translation, python-3.3, django-modeltranslation

i use django-modeltranslation it works good but i have problem defaul language not working, website loads of other languages

my settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ka'

gettext = lambda s: s 

LANGUAGES = [
    ('ka', gettext('Georgian')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('ru', gettext('Russian')),
]

MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'ka'
MODELTRANSLATION_LANGUAGES = ('ka','en','ru')
MODELTRANSLATION_FALLBACK_LANGUAGES = ('ru','en')
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

urls.py config

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^app/', include('app.urls')),
# url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')), # i tried this too
url(r'^set_language/$', 'django.views.i18n.set_language',{},name='set_language'),

)
```

how to fix this problem? what is the solution?